Set Icon in Mac OS version Sonoma using Tkinter
I am trying to change the icon that appears on my tk application for Mac OS.
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()
root.title('Learn To Code at Codemy.com')
root.iconbitmap('/Users/theosmalls/Downloads/IMG_4175.png')

root.mainloop()

Every time I try running the code, it keeps putting the default preview image for Mac which was not what I intended. Why won't this work for Mac OS? Is there an ultimate solution that will work cross-platform?

I don't think iconbitmap() supports PNG image.  Use iconphoto() instead.
